# Is the Restriction of a Continuous Map again a Continuous Function?

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Is true that if $g:Y\to Y$ is continuous then a mapping $f:X\to Y$ with $X \subset Y$ is continuous?

I think it's true. Since for every open set $U$ in $Y$, we have that $g^{-1}(U)$ is open in $Y$.

Because $f^{-1}(U)=g^{-1}(U)\cap X$, it should follow that, $f^{-1}(U)$ is open in $X$.

So $f$ is continuous.

Comment: Do you mean that $f$ is the restriction of $g$ to $X$?

Comment: If you do mean that then yes, I believe you are correct.